# unable to pass different parameters such as 2 String(s) and 2 String[] array parameter to the SQL using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql

Query is working when I try to put a `String` in `MapSqlParameterSource`, but when I try to add a `String[]` I get an invalid column type error.

**How can I use both `String` and `String[]` in a `MapSqlParameterSource` when using sql?**

Any help is appreciated.

```
sql.append(" Select a.* ");
sql.append(" from CONTRACT_OVERSIGHT_REVIEW a,CONTRACT_OVERSIGHT_PROGRAM b ");
sql.append(" where ");
sql.append(" a.ID_CONTRACTOR = :contractorId ");
sql.append(" and a.TYPE_REVIEW in (:reviewType) ");     
sql.append(" and a.SFY = :sfy ");           
sql.append(" and  a.ID_CONTRACT_OVERSIGHT_REVIEW = b.ID_CONTRACT_OVERSIGHT_REVIEW ");               
sql.append("  and b.CD_PROGRAM in (:program)"); 

// Probably should be MapSqlParameterSource<String, Object> or something like that.
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

parameters.addValue("contractorId", contractorId); // Type String
parameters.addValue("reviewType", reviewType); // Type String[]
parameters.addValue("sfy", sfy); // Type String
parameters.addValue("program", program); // Type String[]

List<ContractOversightReview> results 
= jdbcNameTemplate.query(sql.toString(), parameters,
(RowMapper<ContractOversightReview>) (rs, rowNumber) -> /* etc... */);
```

Comment: Could you include the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: Try adding list of strings rather than an array?

Comment: SystemErr     R org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL ----- Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Comment: Issue is Resolved i converted String [] to List<string> as suggested by @moilejter and added Strings and List<string> to Map and passed it as parameter  the SQL executed without any error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by converting String [] to List as suggested by 
     @moilejter 
    and added Strings and List to Map and passed it as parameter  the SQL 
    executed without any error.

```
    List<String> reviewTypeList = Arrays.asList(reviewType); 
    List<String> programList = Arrays.asList(program);
    Map param = new HashMap();
    param.put("contractorId", contractorId);
    param.put("sfy", sfy);
    param.put("reviewType", reviewTypeList);
    param.put("program", programList);
```